# Calling a jQuery plugin inside another plugin stops working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I used 2 jQuery plugins, one called Cycle, use to loop through images when mouse is hover on (stops looping when mouse is outside TV) and the other one called Cursometer, used to track the mouse speed. I want to integrate the 2 plugins together such that the speed of the looping depends on the speed of the mouse. However, when I add the part of the Cycle API call into the speed attribute of Cursometer, the Cycle function stops working. I am very new to JQuery, does this have anything to do with scoping or immediate calling, why wouldn't the Cycle plugin part code work when I include it in the other plugin call (Cursometer)?

example of how Cycle should work: http://jsfiddle.net/sealife24/rwmLf63r/2/

**JSfiddle here:** http://jsfiddle.net/sealife24/wsvoyue5/

```
    $('.slideshow-block').cursometer({
        onUpdateSpeed: function(mouseSpeed) {
            // mouseSpeed is the current cursor speed
            var currSpeed = parseInt(mouseSpeed);
            $speedometer.text(mouseSpeed);

            /* cycle plugin begin */
            $('.slides').cycle({
                fx:     'none',
                speed:   100,   // want to pass currSpeed here, but it didn't work, even doesn't work with a number here
                timeout: 70

            }).cycle("pause");

            $('.slideshow-block').hover(function(){
                $(this).find('.slides').addClass('active').cycle('resume');
            }, function(){
                $(this).find('.slides').removeClass('active').cycle('pause');
            });
            /* cycle plugin end */

        }

        /* if move the cycle plugin part here, cycle will work, but there is no way I could dynamically get the mouseSpeed from the Cursometer plugin */

    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems we can not set speed or time out dynamically to this plugin. I tried and this is what i could achieve.

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/38huk1tz/)

```
 var $speedometer = $('#speedometer');

$('.slideshow-block').cursometer({
    onUpdateSpeed: function(mouseSpeed) {
        var currSpeed = parseInt(mouseSpeed*100);
        $speedometer.text(currSpeed);
        var slide= $(this).find('.slides');
        var opts = slide.data("cycle.opts");
        opts.timeout = currSpeed==0?(0.1):currSpeed;
        slide.cycle("resume");
        /* cycle plugin begin */
               /* cycle plugin end */

    }
});
 $('.slides').cycle({
            fx:     'none',
           // speed:   100,   // want to pass currSpeed here, but it didn't work
            timeout: 70

        }).cycle("pause");;

        $('.slideshow-block').hover(function(){
            $(this).find('.slides').addClass('active').cycle('resume');
        }, function(){
            $(this).find('.slides').removeClass('active').cycle('pause');
        });
```

Comment: It did seem to work well for the first TV, but the second TV is not behaving correctly. Is it because the speed variable need to be the same for all the TVs. I mean, when the cursor is in TV #1, its speed is only applied to TV #1's looping speed, but TV #2 can stay pause?

Comment: wow! this works like charm, you are definitely the best answer. But do you mind explaining a bit of your logic. I've only used couple of jQuery plugins in the past, have no idea how to debug such case, how did you reach to the solution?

Comment: Actually if you don't mind, one more question. The thing I am doing here was trying to mock the effect of this website: http://yeolab.ucsd.edu/yeolab/Lab_Photos/Lab_Photos.html   But from the source code, I can' tell which plugins they used and couldn't understand it. Do you by any chance know if this is a similar problem or even complicated one? Thank you!

Comment: I had to go through the plugins code :) not in depth though. i understood that he is not handling cases except for some next pause etc to be called once plugin is instantiated and also saw that he is saving options in data variable. so that is a little hack to change the timeout value

Comment: I see, so I do need to understand the plugin code. I guess it will take me a long time! Anyways, the above mentioned website's album looks very nice, I like the feature that you can go forward and backward based on your mouse direction, but really don't know if this is some crazy work out there. Just wanted to see your comments on it.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I looked at the plugins you're using, and the cursometer, is straightforward you got that part. For the slides plugin you should be able to just put currSpeed in for the speed variable, then instead of calling 'pause', if you call 'next' as the command string, that forces it to the next slide in the loop. Let me know how this works for you, I will help you out here as much as possible.

```
   $('.slideshow-block').cursometer({
        onUpdateSpeed: function(mouseSpeed) {
            // mouseSpeed is the current cursor speed
            var currSpeed = parseInt(mouseSpeed);  
            /* cycle plugin begin */
            $('.slides').cycle({
                fx:     'none',
                speed:   currSpeed, //call currSpeed variable here
                timeout: 70
            }).cycle('next'); //call next to force the new slide to appear
        }    
    }); //this covers the part of the slide show when you move the mouse over it

   //this should be called outside of the above function so that it doesn't conflict,
  // but I'm not sure what you are doing with it
    $('.slideshow-block').hover(function(){
            $(this).find('.slides').addClass('active').cycle('resume');
        }, function(){
            $(this).find('.slides').removeClass('active').cycle('pause');
    });
```

I hope this helps you out, please let me know if this answer has helped you in anyway

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply Mark. It is my fault I didn't state clearly for the Cycle plugin, I'd like the images to stop looping when my mouse is out of the TV, when the mouse is on, it will resume looping. So if this is the case, changing pause to next will not work. My bad, didn't specify that clearly!

Comment: ah okay, also I don't think your fiddle is working properly can you please take a look at it again and comment back if it is working?

Comment: Yup, you are right. Now the first fiddle, showing how Cycle should work, is the correct version. All I want to do next is to make the speed dependent on the cursor speed.